# Why 'git remote show <name>' display remote HEAD is ambiguous, may be one of the following

Tags: git

Why when I run 'git remote show ' why it said

```
  HEAD branch (remote HEAD is ambiguous, may be one of the following):
    dev
    master
  Remote branches:
    dev                                   tracked
    master                                tracked
```

why git does not know the remote HEAD branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the SHA1 reference by `remote/HEAD` is the same than `remote/master` or `remote/dev`.

You can find more details at "[Error with git: remote HEAD is ambiguous, may be one of the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575984/6309)".

As mentioned in this [more recent thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/remote-s-HEAD-not-detected-correctly-td6074877.html) (2011):

> Right. The transport protocol doesn't expose the name that a symbolic
>   reference points to, only its current value. Thus clients are forced
>   to guess by looking for another reference whose current SHA-1 is the
>   same. If there is more than one, its taking a best guess.
>
> There have been a few attempts to expand the protocol and include the
>   current symbolic reference target name, but thus far it hasn't gotten
>   much beyond the idea stage.

A [patch has been proposed](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/102039) though (but only as a "a quick-and-dirty patch for local repositories").