# Syncing repository branches with a remote repository in git

Tags: git, macos, github

I just got a mac and I'm having issues with command line git. When I clone a repository, none of the branches are being tracked. Is there a way to clone a repository and also clone the branches locally? I know that I can make a new local branch and track a remote branch, but I don't want to have to do that for every branch in the repository.

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/9PMComplete
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/LinkUpdate
  remotes/origin/Safari
  remotes/origin/TableUpdate
  remotes/origin/Update_1.0.1
  remotes/origin/Update_1.0.2
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/onclick
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that remote tracking branches (the ones in `refs/remotes/origin` namespace) are not tracked locally on purpose.
See "[Tracking Branches and Remote Tracking Branches: Summary](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/)".

Only the [default branch of the remote repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32503667/6309) is tracked locally.

That avoid having too many branches to deal with at the beginning.

If you have to track all branches, see "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309)"