# git command to get name of base branch

Tags: git

Often `master` is the base branch but not always. Is there a git command that can tell me the name of the base branch? I want to use this to make some git aliases for commands that need to know the base branch name and I want these aliases to be useful across repositories where the base branch may differ.

Comment: Have you tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch

Comment: Git does not really have the concept of a "base" branch. Branches are all independent: they're just pointers, pointing to one specific commit. Each branch name *can* have one (at most, or zero is the other option) *upstream* setting but typically those are remote-tracking names: the upstream for `master` is `origin/master`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

"Base branch" -> This isn't actually a git construct. There is no such thing as a "base branch" in git.

There *is* such a thing as a default branch for bitbucket or github, though. The best way to figure this out might be to use e.g. [github's REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) to figure that out. cURLing `https://api.github.com/repos/djhaskin987/degasolv` would, for example, return a JSON object with `default_branch` field in it giving that repo's default branch of `develop`.

If you're just cloning a generic git repository though, [it seems that whatever is in HEAD will be checked out when that git repo is cloned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18726037/850326).