# Get the default branch of a remote repository with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am working on a Git client, and right now I am trying to implement the checkout of a specific branch. I have a combo box that I populate with branch names, and I would like to find out which branch is the default, so that I can set it as the preselected item in the combo box when connecting to a valid Git repository.

I am listing all the remote branches as you can see below, but I cannot figure out which is the default one.

```java
Map<String, Ref> callAsMap = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
    .setRemote("https://github.com/example")
    .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
    .callAsMap();
```

So, is there a way (standard or "hacky") to detect which `Ref` object represents the default branch? And how can I get its name?

Comment: You should be able to chain a `.get("HEAD")` after this for the default-branch.

Comment: Tried this, but how can I find out the name of the default branch? If I invoke `getName()` the answer is `HEAD`. But I expected something like `master`, because that's the name of one of my repos' default branch.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Comment: Hm, I felt like none solved the problem. But in the end, it seems that it cannot really detect which is the default, because there might not be a default advertised, right?

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru Did you get any solution for getting the default branch using Jgit

Comment: Um, this was quite a long time ago, but it doesn't seem I found a solution. I just worked around this issue for my use case.

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru what is your workaround? can you share some details?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I am in child care leave

Answer (score 2):

`Repository::getFullBranch` returns the current branch of the local repository.

To get the default branch of a remote repository, you need to ask for its `HEAD` ref. The map that is returned by the snippet that you posted should contain an entry with key `HEAD` and (if I'm not mistaken) a value that denotes the name of the default branch.

If `HEAD` refers to an object id, you could obtain a list of all remote refs with `repository.getRefDatabase().getRefs(Constants.R_REMOTES)` to look up the HEAD id. This approach may be inaccurate as multiple refs could point to the same object id.

Note that it is not required for a remote repository to advertise a default branch.

See also these posts for how C-Git finds the default branch: [git - how to get default branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch) and [What determines default branch after "git clone"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726037/what-determines-default-branch-after-git-clone))

Comment: Hmmm, I already tried that yesterday, and I remember the name for `HEAD` was simply a hashcode. I'd like to find the "real" name, such as `master` or `dev`...

Comment: Hm, that's what I feared. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the chain with `.get("HEAD")`, if it is a symbolic link, you can chain it with `.getTarget().getName()` to "extract" its name e.g.

```
Map<String, Ref> callAsMap = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
.setRemote("https://github.com/example")
.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
.callAsMap().get("HEAD").getTarget().getName()
```

Source: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jgit-dev/msg03320.html